# Languages whose Parikh image is recognizable

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be some alphabet, and $p : \Sigma^* \to \mathbb N_0^{|\Sigma|}$ the [Parikh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem#Definitions_and_formal_statement). A formal language $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is called a *slip*-language, if $p(L)$ is a [semilinear set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_arithmetic_progression#Semilinear_sets). By [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem), every context-free language is a slip-language. But not every slip-language is context-free. For example, the commutative closure of $(abc)^*$ is not context-free.

In $\mathbb N_0^k$ with $k = |\Sigma|$, the semilinear set are precisely the [rational sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_set). The [recognizable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recognizable_set) in $\mathbb N_0^k$ are finite unions of sets of the form $R_1 \times \ldots \times R_k$, with each $R_i$, for $i \in \{1,\ldots, k\}$, either finite or ultimately periodic.

The slip languages are an established concept. For example, we have [work from the 70's](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000071800247), and such neat results as that the commutative closure of binary slip languages is [context-free](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X03003354).

Now I am just curious. Is there anything known, or is there any research, on languages whose Parikh image is recognizable?

As recognizability is preserved under inverse homomorphism, the commutative closure of such a language is regular. But, there exist non-regular languages whose Parikh image is recognizable. For example, the language given by the context-free grammar $A \to aBaA | \varepsilon, B \to bAbB |\varepsilon$. It has the commutative closure
$$
 \{ w \in \{a,b\}^* \mid |w|_{a} \equiv 0 \pmod{2}, |w|_b \equiv 0 \pmod{2},
 |w|_a \ge \min\{1, |w|_b\}. \},
$$
where $|w|_a$ and $|w|_b$ denote the number of $a$'s, respectively $b$'s, in $w$.

EDIT (8 May 2020): There was an error in the specification of the context-free grammar. I corrected it. Also I will give the proofs, just to be on the safe side. Let $L$ be the language generated by the grammar. Suppose it where regular with pumping constant $N$. Consider $w = (ab)^N(ba)^N \in L$, and let $v$ be some pumpable factor in $(ab)^N$. As any word in $L$ must have even length, this factor itself must have even length. Hence it starts with different symbols. So, we either have $w = (ab)^x(ab)^y(ab)^z(ba)^N$ with $N = x+y+z$ and $v = (ab)^y$, or $w = (ab)^xa(ba)^yb(ab)^z(ba)^N$ with $N - 1 = x+y+z$ and $v = (ba)^y$. But in either case, none of the pumped up strings would be in $L$, as they still only contain $bb$ as a factor with two consecutive equal symbols. But if the factor $bb$ (or $aa$) only appears once in a given word from $L$, it must have the form $(ab)^k(ba)^k$ or $(ab)^{k-1}aa(ab)^{k-1}$ for some $k > 0$. Alternatively, we could note that an infinite accepting automaton is given by the state set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, with the letter $a$ interchanging $1$ and $2$, $3$ and $4$, and so on, and $b$ interchanging $2$ and $3$, $4$ and $5$ and so. As this is a permutation automaton with the single final state $\{1\}$, it is minimal.
Finally, as $(aa)^{n-1}a(bb)^ma \in L$ for each $m \ge 0$, $n > 0$, and $(aa)^m \in L$ for each $m \ge 0$, and every word in $L$ has an even number of $a$'s and $b$'s, the claim about the commutative closure is implied.

EDIT (14 July 2021): The claim about the "infinite" permutation automaton made in the previous EDIT-block is wrong. I overlooked that we need a transition labelled with $b$ at the state $1$ too. Adding, for example, a self-loop would change the language (but still, nonetheless, gives an example of a non-regular language having regular commutative closure).

Comment: I'm not sure if it will give you a clear answer, but a lot of the concepts you mention arise often when studying VASS (vector addition systems with states). Perhaps some of the results there will shed light on this.

Comment: @Shaull Thanks. At least it gives me a direction to look for :) Btw, if you know some specific resources/surveys about VASS, feel free to share them!

Comment: VASSs are mentioned often in https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00727025v2

Comment: I vaguely remember the concept of Parikh automata, as discussed here. http://cds.cern.ch/record/1321204?ln=en However, I cannot tell how well that automaton model fits with your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seems that I was quite confused back then. This language class is precisely the language class of those languages, whose commutative closure is regular.

Let $\Sigma = \{a_1, \ldots, a_k\}$. One implication is given in the question. For the other, suppose the commutative closure of $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is regular, i.e., the set $p^{-1}(p(L))$ is regular.
Then,  $p^{-1}(p(L)) \cap a_1^* \cdots a_k^*$ is regular, bounded and has the same Parikh image as $L$ or its commutative closure. By an old result of Ginsburg (see below), we can write this language as a finite union of languages of the form $A_1 \cdots A_k$, where each $A_i$ is a regular subset of $a_i^*$. Now, the Parikh image of one such set has the form $R_1 \times \ldots \times R_k$ with $R_i \subseteq \mathbb N$ recognizable. So, by a condition written in the question, the Parikh image of $L$ is recognizable.

Alternatively, without citing other results, suppose we have a morphism $h : \Sigma^* \to M$ with $M$ finite such that $p^{-1}(p(L)) = h^{-1}(h(L))$. We can assume $M$ is commutative (for example, by taking the syntactic monoid).
Hence, the map $\varphi : \mathbb N_0^k \to M$ given by $\varphi(n_1, \ldots, n_k) = h(a_1)^{n_1} \cdots h(a_k)^{n_k}$ is a morphism.
Then, $p(L) = \varphi^{-1}(h(L))$ and so $p(L)$ is recognizable.

Now, identifying language classes whose commutative closure is regular is quite an active field of research. For example, see the second reference below.

S. Ginsburg, [Bounded Regular Sets](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-05/S0002-9939-1966-0201310-3/S0002-9939-1966-0201310-3.pdf), Amer. Math. Soc. 17 (1966), 1043-1049.

Antonio Cano Gómez, Giovanna Guaiana, Jean-Éric Pin:
[Regular languages and partial commutations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540113000771?via%3Dihub). Inf. Comput. 230: 76-96 (2013)